# Check a User's Login Via Azure MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, azure, mysqli, azure-sql-database

I'm looking to verify a user's login via azure mysql. I can successfully connect to the database. I'm just having problems with the syntax associated with azure mysql. What I found online was for regular sql, but that doesn't seem to be the same.

Currently I have:

```
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT name, email FROM logins where name='$loginname' and password='$loginpassword'');
    if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
    {
        echo("invalid user");
    }
    else
    {
        echo("successful login");
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["user"] = loginname;
        //header("Location: ../question-explanation.html");
    }
```

The error I get is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$loginname' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')' in

Comment: First of all, are those variables escaped?

Comment: @MehdiBounya I used trim when I first got them. I'm going to add in mysqli_real_escape_string once I get this input working

Comment: why didn't you just use a prepared statement? that would have solved many problems; one of which being open to an sql injection.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I hadn't heard of those until you just mentioned them. I just looked them up and I'm going to use them now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not concatenating the data, you need to use `.` to add data to a string:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT name, email FROM logins where name=' . $loginname . ' and password=' . $loginpassword);
```

But you shouldn't concatenate variables to a query because that will open you to SQL injection attacks.

Check [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)